# How get all data of specific document firebase firestore? [maybe transaction?]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, transactions

I am working in a node proyect and I installed firebase package.
This is the structure of my database.
[image]

I want to stract all data of the client aaa@gmail.com in only one operation. I mean
the name, email, age and all addresses....

```
const docClient = doc(db,"Client", "aaa@gmail.com");
const collectionAddresses = collection(docClient, "addresses");
const DataClient = await getDoc(docClient)
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionAddresses);

console.log(DataClient.data());
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

**I think there are too many operations to only extract the customer data found in the same document**

CHAT GPT told me that if I use transactions, both operations are performed as if it were one and he gave me a code that is not working.

But this code is wrong, because I think transaction only works with documents, no collections.

```
try{
await runTransaction(db,async (transaccion)=>{
   
   var collectionAddresses=collection(doc(db,"Client","aaaa@gmail.com"),"addresses");
   var a=await transaccion.get(collectionAddresses);   

});
}catch(errors){
console.log(errors);
}
```

In fact, node print an error for console.....

So my question is if someone knows how can i get all data in only one operation?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get all data in only one operation?

I understand that by "one operation" you mean "one query". With your data model this is not possible. You'll have to query the `client` doc and all the `address` docs.

So for your example (with 3 addresses) you'll pay for 4 document reads.

Note that using a transaction will not change anything from a number of reads perspective. CHAT GPT answer is not very good... The "one operation" that this AI refers to is the fact that changes in a transaction are grouped in an atomic operation, not that there is only one read or one write from/to the Firestore DB.

---

One possible approach would be to store the addresses in an Array in the `client` doc, but you have to be sure that you'll never reach the 1MiB maximum size limit for a document.

Comment: Hey @ignorantnecromancer, did you have the time to look at the answer?